# How fast is a process reading/writing virtual memory?

Tags: linux, performance, virtual-memory, benchmark

We have top, htop, iotop, iostat, vmstat, etc, to measure many different things on Linux, but how can one measure how much MB/s a process is reading and writing to/from RAM, i.e., virtual memory?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's any instrumentation available by default to capture that information. Adding such instrumentation, which basically amounts to running software under a profiler, adds quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: Virtual memory ≠ RAM